# Getting rid of border-bottom in submenus

Tags: html, css

The active link in my navigation has a `border-bottom: 1px solid #424242` but I don't want to have `border-bottom` in the dropdown. As you can see when you mouseover the dropdown the links jump. I've been really trying but I can't find a solution for this. May be I have to refactor the html. I'm confused! Any help? This is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/wntuevrk/). Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code ..?

Comment: can you add some code please. impossible to tell you which element to target in your css without it.

Comment: @ CodeRomeos, @Destination Designs Already did! Sorry.

Comment: You are looking for something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wntuevrk/1/)?

Comment: @lmgonzalves Cool! What was it?

Comment: @Labanino See my answer please :)

Comment: is is just because the link jumps that you want to remove the border bottom?

Comment: Please edit the code from your JSFiddle into your question as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `.top-bar-section ul li a:hover` from:

```
.top-bar-section ul li a:hover, .top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button), .top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
    color: #424242;
    background-color: #f3f4f6;
    background: #f3f4f6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #424242;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wntuevrk/1/)

**EDIT:**

A better solution is to remove the border only in sublists.

```
.top-bar-section ul ul a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

And this is a possible solution to deal with jumping:

```
.top-bar-section > ul > li > a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wntuevrk/3/)

Comment: he is asking to have the submenus with no border which you cannot see in the fiddle he gave because script is missing, but it is in the code.

Comment: I post it as an answer because he want to know about it!

Comment: yea it's a little unclear as to what he means by "sub-menu" i guess. in his demo you dont see the child UL

Comment: @DestinationDesigns It would be `ul li ul`

Comment: @Imgonzalves The purpose of `.top-bar-section ul li a:hover` was to have the border not only when the page is active but when you mouseover the rest of the links. The original fiddle I posted has that functionality. Now with `.top-bar-section ul li a:hover` removed the functionality is gone. Any idea?

Comment: right and so removing .top-bar-section ul li a:hover takes that away. in css we have to be specific as to which element we want to target. so to remove the borders from your sub menu items specifically, you need to target  .top-bar-section>.has-dropdown >li>a or  .top-bar-section>.has-dropdown >li>a:hover see my answer above

Comment: we are both basically targeting the same thing just a different style :)

Comment: @DestinationDesigns Right! ;)

Answer (score 1):

from the looks of it to have the sub-menu items with no border, it would appear as if this would work. In your fiddle you cant see the subs but the code is there for them so:

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown li > a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```